# How do I allow custom .php files to be accessable?

Tags: .htaccess

I have already looked at the [How do I call legacy PHP files?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215065/how-do-i-call-legacy-php-files) answers and they didn't fix my problem.

I have a custom php file in my Drupal site (Hosted on Acquia Cloud and I am working on a local version of the site using Acquia Dev Desktop) that needs to be accessable, I added these lines to my .htaccess file trying to allow access to the php file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/learning/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/learning/sales/[^/]*\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/learning/sales/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/learning/sales/ajax/[^/]*\.php$
```

But I still get this response trying to go to the index.php file.
"Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /learning/sales/ on this server."

How can I fix this?

Note: if I change the file to be index.html it works just fine (well my ajax call in it doesn't work but it atleast loads) but if it is index.php it returns with the 403 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/learning/[^/]*\.php$
```

For more info please look at this thread, [unable to run custom php script inside drupal](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2017-02-07/d8-unable-to-run-custom-php-script-within-drupal).

Comment: I tried that and read the entire thread and none of those worked for me. it is still giving me a 403 error, would that mean that the problem might be related to something else?

Comment: Have you cleared the cache?

Comment: do you mean the drupal site cache or my browser cache? I am just tried the drupal cache and no luck.

Comment: Maybe the files don't have the correct permission?

Comment: Maybe, but when I look at the files on my computer (running a local Acquia Dev Desktop version of the site) it looks like their permissions are 777 so that shouldn't be a problem right?)

Comment: Ok, I went back through the link you sent and for some reason putting my rewritecond lines in the exact place he did at the very bottom of the comments on that page worked. Thanks @Jdrupal!